# Create a binary tree in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have a sequence with n numbers and i want to create a data structure to answer the following question:
sequence `n = [5 ,7, 4, 24, 8, 3, 12, 34]`
I want the `min(2,5)` then the answer is 3 because `a2=7, a3=4, a4=24, a5=8`. So the min(i,j) returns the position of minimum number between (i,j).
I thought that a good data structure to save this sequence would be a complete binary tree to save the sequence numbers at leaves. But how can i implement this structure in O(n)?

Comment: I want the data structure to be created in O(n), all the numbers of sequence to be at leaves, and the question of min(i,j) i want to be answered in O(logn)

Comment: It looks like it is range minimum query you are looking for. There you can indeed construct the structure in linear time and then get constant time minimum-index answers. It is not trivial, though, and involves Cartatian trees. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query

Comment: What's the problem with implementing your data structure in O(n)? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a Segment Tree with range minimum query. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-range-minimum-query/) is detailed explanation of it. Building time is `O(n)`, because there are in tree no more than `2 * n` nodes, so final time complexity will be `O(n)`.

If you need to find not only the minimum value, but also the position, then inside the vertex you need to store not only the minimum, but also where it was reached. How to update such a structure seems clear: when you recalculate the minimum in the father, you need to see from which son it is received and take the corresponding position of the minimum from the son. For leaves, the positions are equal to the positions of the leaves themselves.